# Pattern drawing using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, logic

I am trying to draw two patterns and am stuck with different problems:

1)

```
******************* 
****************** 
***************** 
**************** 
*************** 
************** 
************* 
************ 
*********** 
********** 
********* 
******** 
******* 
****** 
***** 
**** 
*** 
** 
* 
NULL
```

I have written the below query to get this:

```
select CASE WHEN (r2-r1)!=0 THEN
         rpad('*',r2-r1,'*') END 
from (select rownum r1
          ,(max(level) over ()) as r2 
     from dual 
    connect by level<=20);
```

Problem i am facing(if you look at the pic) is null is coming at the end. I am not able to figure a way to get rid of that.

2) I am trying to draw the same pattern with spaces in between every star. Stuck here too..

All the help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: You are facing two problems, you only caught the NULL at the end but if you needed the longest string to be 20 asterisks, it's not - it is only 19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQL> select rpad('*', level, '*') as c from dual connect by level <= 20 order by 
     length(c) desc;

C
------------------------------------
********************
*******************
******************
*****************
****************
***************
**************
*************
************
***********
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*

20 rows selected.

SQL> select rpad('*', 2*level-1, ' *') as c from dual connect by level <= 20 order by 
     length(c) desc;

C
--------------------------------------------------
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * *
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*

20 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out the row where maximum equals ROWNUM:

```
SELECT
    rpad('*', r2 - r1, '*') c1,
    rpad('* ', (r2 - r1) * 2, '* ') c2
FROM
    (SELECT ROWNUM r1, max(LEVEL) OVER () AS r2 FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20)
WHERE
    r1 < r2
```